# Series solution of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution of the differential equations.

$2t^2y"+3ty'-(1+t)y=0$

this is from a section on series solutions but I'm a bit confused on how to solve this, and honestly don't really understand series solutions. We have been learning about regular singular points but I am not really sure if this has something to do with the solution or not. I'll start with finding the regular singular points:

$tp(t)=3/2$ $t^2q(t)=\frac{-(1+t)}{2t^2}$

So they don't have regular singular points at t=0. This is where my confusion comes in, because in all the examples in my book when they find general solutions of the equations they all have regular singular points at t=0 so I wasn't how this changes things.

In the examples of my book they use a  summation of $a_nt^{n+r}$bfor y and then calculate y' and y". Is this what I need t do?

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Try assuming a solution of the form 
$$ y = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n t^n $$
Then, $y'$ and $y''$ are equal to what? 
Substitute these into the differential equation, and solve $a_n$ for each $n$.